# Latex chapter customise- titlesec

Tags: formatting, titlesec

I'm trying to make a template theme and I'm having a hard time. I can't see how to do this. I can change the colour of chapters and sections, but don't know how to put the number of chapter in black (like the image) and neither get the right colour. Then ask how difficult its to make that rectangle in each chapter(with the right height).

For now i have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report} % Documento two sided
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdftex,dvipsnames,usenames,nonamebreak,table]{xcolor}

\colorlet{Cyan}{cyan!200}
\colorlet{sectboxcolor}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{secnumcolor}{Black}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
%{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\color{Cyan}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{Cyan}\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{Cyan}}{\textcolor{secnumcolor}{\thesection}}{1em}{}
}
```

[image: Its a collage of pictures]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  What is the right height of the left thick rule? Anfd do you want only the chapter number black, or also Capítulo?

Comment: Thx! I want to imitate the image. I dont have the actual values, but i think that is 2 or less inches. I want the number and the chapter (capitulo its chapter in spanish), then the chapters name in colour.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposition. Note that now, `utf8` is the default input encoding, so you don't have to declare it. Also, the `usenames` option is the default  for `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, spanish]{report} % Documento two sided
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdftex,dvipsnames,svgnames,nonamebreak,table]{xcolor}

\colorlet{Cyan}{cyan!200}
\colorlet{sectboxcolor}{cyan!30}
\colorlet{secnumcolor}{Black}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\sffamily\huge\bfseries\filright}{\hspace{0.6em}\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\color{CornflowerBlue}\raisebox{-6pt}[0pt]{\rule{0.3em}{10pc}\hspace{0.3em}}\Huge}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{Cyan}}{\textcolor{secnumcolor}{\thesection}}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{Introducción}

\section{Primera sección}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excelente! Thx! I need to learn how to do this with out help. How i add the colour square next two the section name?

Comment: It is a simple `\rule{width}{height}` command, slightly ‘raised’ downwards (by 6pt). To avoid increasing the vertical spacing between chapter number and chpater title, I used the first optional argument of `\raisebox`, which is the height of the raised box to make latex believe it is 0pt high (the second optional argument would be the depth of the box, but it is unnecessary to use it here). The colour is simply given by the `\color{CornflowerBlue}` command in the last argument, where I put the rule command, so both rule and title are coloured. Am I clear?

Comment: Yea perfect! Thx again! Im reading the documentation to understand a little bit. The only thing that now i cant do, its to put the square before the number of section.`\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{frenchblue}}{\textcolor{secnumcolor}{\thesection}}{1em}{\color{frenchblue}\raisebox{-0pt}[0pt]{\rule{0.5em}{1.5pc}\hspace{0.3em}}\Huge}`

Comment: yea, its work but puts number of section, square and then section name. I want square then number of section then section name.

Comment: As I see  it, this should work (the default style is `hang`): `\titleformat{\section} {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{frenchblue}}{\textcolor{secnumcolor}{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt]{\rule{0.5em}{1.5pc}}\thesection}}{1em}{\color{frenchblue}\Huge}`. The `\hspace{0.3em}` is not necessary here, it was there only to compensate for a correct alignment of the first line in display style.

Comment: Please see my  previous comment (I could not edit the first one, so I deleted it to replace with a correct version of the code).

Comment: Thx! I can belive i didnt realice that! Thats perfect!

Comment: I advise to delve a bit into the code to understand exactly what each command does.